# How to install MCP on Eclipse with no errors?

Tags: java, minecraft, mcps

I need help to use or to install MCP on Eclipse with no erorrs.
I've got CMS Erorr with my Java 64-bit Server. I want to make mods for Minecraft Forge 1.7.10. I need a Forge client.jar.

Comment: MCP means "Minecraft Coder Pack"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a mod for Minecraft, you want to be using Forge. Follow the [tutorial here.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/master/README.txt) If it doesn't work, come back with any error messages you're getting.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you also program Mods?

Comment: How to setup MCP 9.0.8 with Forge, Eclipse and Git Hub through EGit?

Comment: I use Java, how to do it in Java?